# Where can I see the Log when Uber webhook encounters error?

Tags: uber-api

I am building a Uber client application that uses Delivery API, there is a webhook that would constantly update the status changed of the delivery process.

My question is there any place or url that allow me to view the webhook requests/error log on Uber platform?

I want to know when my own server is down, Uber would have a place for me to check when does the downtime occurred by viewing the log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monitoring functionality is not currently provided by the Uber Developer Platform. If webhooks fail to be delivered to your app, there is an [exponential retry strategy](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/webhooks#errors-and-retry-strategy) employed.